# No suitable driver found

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

I am trying to execute a sql query in java 6:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;


/**
 *
 * @author ramy
 */
public class JavaTest 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            String url="jdbc:msql://127.0.0.1:1521;DatabaseName=test";
            Connection ct=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");
            Statement st=ct.createStatement();
            ResultSet result;
            result=st.executeQuery("select * from utente");
            while(result.next())
            {
                String temp=result.getString("Num_tessera");
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
            ct.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have installed mysql 5.5 cluster on Mac Os X, in the url I have just written my local IP (localhost), and the database name is test.
Why doesn't it find the database? Do I have to install some driver? I already have the database installed and "utente" is an existing table.

Comment: just out of curiosity (if you've got the driver in classpath the faulty bits are probably in connection url), can you add the stacktrace of the exception raised ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the problem is your JDBC URL:

```
"jdbc:msql://..."
```

Did you mean

```
"jdbc:mysql://..."
```

by any chance?

(And yes, you'll *also* need the [MySQL driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) in your classpath. It's not something you need to *install*, but the jar file will need to be available.)

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you have MySQL JDBC Driver in your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

also please check the port in your URL , as 1521 is Oracle and MySQL is 3306