# drivers loaded in apache-tomcat-6.0.36/lib but still get No suitable driver found

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I am learning web services in eclipse helios with axis 2 and apache tomcat. I have two dynamic web projects with java classes that successfully connect to two databases when I run them as simple java classes in eclipse. (I have added the external jars to the external build path for the project). But when I run either on the server, I get an error: `No suitable driver found`. I know that I need to [load the necessary drivers](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTinG_zY7VsxYk9ESo0OZ3iYTpVt6NfuZVQh3_8fZ@mail.gmail.com) into `apache-tomcat-6.0.36/lib` and I have done so (and re-started the server). (see [No suitable driver found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447041/no-suitable-driver-found)).

I use this statement to create the driver in my Java class:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"); //throws class not found exception w/message "com.postgresql.jdbc.Driver"
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```

Why doesn't apache "see" the .jar drivers in its /lib folder? Some older tutorials say to put the .jars in common/lib--but I don't see that folder in my apache tomcat directory structure. What can I do to debug this problem?

Comment: Add the jar to your project lib, under `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: The correct Driver qualified class name  is `org.postgresql.Driver`

Comment: I added the drivers to /apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/axis2/WEB-INF/lib. Do I need to add them to the project's WEB-INF/lib before making the .aar file as well?

Comment: Yes, I meant put them in the project's `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: so put them in /workspace/PersonalInfoService/WebContent/WEB-INF and then go to the sub-directory /workspace/PersonalInfoService/WebContent/WEB-INF/services/PersonalInfoService to run jar cvf PersonalInfoService.aar ./*

Comment: No, create a `lib` directory in `/workspace/PersonalInfoService/WebContent/WEB-INF` and put it there. As to how you run the `aar`, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of Java (and thus, the JDBC version) you use, you might need to call `Class.forName()` before calling `DriverManager.getConnection(...)`. This forces the JVM to load the class, so that JDBC knows the class is a driver for your type of connection. Without that, JDBC knows no driver for your type of database and thus spits out the "No suitable driver found".

If you're running your class in Eclipse using Java 7 (and thus JDBC 4.0) the drivers that are found in your class path are automatically loaded. With Java versions before 7 (and thus JDBC before 4.0), you have to register your driver by hand, like explained. See the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html) for details.

Comment: yes and putting it inside a try{...} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) is a good idea

Comment: I added the statement and it is throwing a class not found exception

Comment: The JDBC driver for PostgreSQL is `org.postgresql.Driver` ([source](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/tomcat.html)).

Answer (score 0):

If this line is uncommented in `${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/server.xml`:

```
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
```

Change it to:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" driverManagerProtection="false" />
```

This returns Tomcat to `pre-6.0.35` functionality, where it correctly registered the type 4 JDBC drivers in `${CATALINA_HOME}/lib`.